# How do I make an adonis.js view?

Tags: javascript, html, frameworks, view, adonis.js

I have just started using adonisjs in order to make a site dynamic , replacing repeating elements with blocks.In this case , I'm using views. Problem is , I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have a html page named mainpage.html , and adonis.html .
In mainpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{# resources/views/mainpage.html #}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>NextAnime</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block latestEntries %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

In adonis.html

```
{# resources/views/adonis.html #}
{% extends 'mainpage' %}

var rangeEntries = [0,1,2,3,4]

{% block latestEntries %}

    {% for i in range %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="anotherpage.html"><img src="../../public/images/justanimage.jpeg" id="latest_entry_image" alt="Some problem"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <a href="anotherpage.html">name of anime</a>
            <p>Chapters/Volumes :</p>
            <p>Date</p>
        </div>
    </div><br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

PS : the official documentation isn't clear about the {% extends '' %} part. Do I put the name of the html document (mainpage) or the alias I assign in the HomeController.js file (main)?

In HomeController.js :

```
class HomeController {

  * index (request, response) {
    const view = yield response.view('adonis')
    response.send(view)
  }
  * main (request, response) {
    const view = yield response.view('mainpage')
    response.send(view)
  }
}
```

And lastly , how to I know when I reached the end of a list in general, in adonis, please.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out the following two cases:

- Changed the name of the html document (changed it to mainpage1.html) but did not change the name in the `{% extends '' %}` (kept it as mainpage).
- Changed the name in the `{% extends '' %}` (changed it to mainPage1 but the template name is mainPage.html).

From what I tried out, I understood the following:

- You will have to put the name of the template with out the '.html' extenstion while extending a template (in this case 'mainPage.html' and while extending `{% extends 'mainPage' %}`). When the controller sends a response using `response.send(view)`, it gets the template from the `resources/views/` directory using the template name excluding the `.html` extension.

Please try out the different methods related to template extension and inclusion.